# Remove all href links using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove all the links from a parsed site which has then had a div removed and placed in the main code. The problem is that I am trying to remove all the 'href' links in the extracted div but am unable to get anywhere. I have tried using 'CSS' and works but only in chrome and I have to use IE. I have looked at 'php simple html dom' parser to see if i could do it before the file is saved but can't get anything to work. so my last resort is to use 'jquery' but the problem is that the links to remove is being extracted from the file and is not directly in the code. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it. below is the code I am using.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=500" />
   <title>example News</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/wwwRand1.css">
   <?php 
      include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
      $html=file_get_html( 'http://example.com/home.php'); 
      $html->save('site/result.htm')                      
      ?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('document').ready(function() {
      $('#postsArea').load('site/result.htm #postsArea');
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="postsArea"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What... are... those... tables?

Comment: Sorry about that I was in a rush and left all junk in the code I have updated it now and hopefully it is readable.

Comment: It's not about it being readable or not to us, but I was thinking what the heck are _you_ doing with those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the href attribute from the `<a />` tags

```
$("#postsArea").load( "site/result.htm", function() {
   $("#postsArea a").removeAttr("href")
});
```

If you still want the tags to appear clickable...

```
$("#postsArea a").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply but seems to not be working, instead of extracting a div and displaying it, it now extracts the whole web page. I will link my html code to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: Just add $("#postsArea a").removeAttr("href") after youve done the load in your original code.

Comment: Thank you it works, but the button still works but now leads to a dead end. is there a way to remove the button completely?

Comment: no worry's I solved my problem using `$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#postsArea').click(function (event)
        {
        event.preventDefault();
        });` Thank you for all your help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
         url : 'site/result.htm',
         dataType: 'html',
         success : function(html){
              $html = $(html).find(a).attr("href", "");
              $("#postsArea").html($html);
         },
         error : function(){
              $("#postArea").html("<div>No Data Found.</div>");
         }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href]').each(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                    
      var link =  jQuery(this);
      link.after(jQuery('<span/>').text(link.text()));
      link.remove();
    });
});
```

It replaces `<a href="foo">Foo</a>` with `<span>Foo</span>`.